# Speed up SQLite start up?

Tags: performance, sqlite, database-connection, startup

For speeding up query, I divide our app sqlite schema from one single table to multipart tables.

However, the sqlite startup becomes slower and slower when the number of tables reaches about 10 thousands.

And the document mentions: "Whenever a database is opened, the entire schema is scanned and parsed and a parse tree for the schema is held in memory. That means that database connection startup time and initial memory usage is proportional to the size of the schema." (https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)

Is there any idea to help speed up the start up and keep multipart tables schema?

Comment: Properly optimizing the single-table schema would be much easier. But you did not ask for that.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to avoid the long startup time is to avoid the startup, i.e., to keep your application running and its database connection open.